# Specific K-d trees modification

Tags: algorithm, tree

it is now that to store N-dimensional data one can use k-d tries. 
My specific question is  , what could be modified if we have fixed 3D space ( that is its boundaries does not change ) and incoming events with each one having the 4th dimension ( time ) constantly increasing .  First thought is to use function f(t) = 1/2^t which would approach slowly zero .... Does that make sense ? :)

Answer (score 0):

What kind of queries do you want to do on the data?

Easiest would be a k-d tree for the spatial dimensions, and some simple ordered data-structure for the time. If there are very few items with the exact same spatial position, then a simple list should suffice.

```cs
new KDTree<double, List<Item>>(3)
```

where the `Item` type contains fields for both spatial and temporal positions.

If the number of spatially coinciding points could get larger, you could swap the list for a binary search tree.